# jquery ajax модальное окно с ajax. После закрытия окна и открытия его снова функция не работает

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap4

Есть ссылка ведущая на модальное окно, внутри которого три кнопки при нажатии на одну из них активируется ajax запрос к серверу, после которого пользователь закрывает окно. Если без перезагрузки страницы снова нажать на ссылку, то откроется модальное окно с уже запомненным ответом от сервера. Как сделать, чтобы форма после закрытия открывалась и работала в первоначальном состоянии?

```js
$(function(){

    $('#subs > button').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var days = $(event.target).attr("id");

      $.post('subs.php', {'data' : days}).done(function(data){
          if(JSON.parse(data) === true){
            $("#subs").html("<p>Подписка успешно продлена!</p>");
          }else{
            $("#subs").html("<p>Что-то пошло не так!</p>");
          }
      })
    });

  })
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Выберите срок действия</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="closeSub">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body d-flex justify-content-around" id = "subs">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id = "30-days">30 дней / 150р</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id = "60-days">60 дней / 300р</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id = "90-days">90 дней / 500р</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение - использовать $(form).reset(); в случае успеха, где form - это идентификатор формы, например $("form.form") или $("form#subscribe").

Однако, учитывая, что у вас нет формы как таковой (ох уж этот js), то вам придется самому сбрасывать все состояния. Можете написать функцию для этого, а потом вызывать ее после отправки "формы".

Answer (score 0):

Так и поступил! Склонировал html код перед событием и вставил его после с предшествующим удалением. Единственное, пришлось еще сделать рекурсивный js, засунув его в функцию, которая вызывалась каждый раз после закрытия окна. Спасибо за помощь!